# Auto-generate Objective-C method headers from implementation?

Tags: objective-c, header

Is there a tool that will take a list of Objective-C methods and produce the corresponding header definitions?

Often when writing code in my implementation file, I find I need to add, remove, or modify method definitions. This requires the tedious (and thoroughly-automatable) step of switching back to my header file and making the exact same changes, twice.

What ever happened to DRY? What kind of tools can I use to make life easier here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Accessorizer:
http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html

It automates most work regarding properties, it might work for methods too.

Sadly, it's not free.

Comment: This seems like the best working answer to the question, although I'm still pretty surprised that in this day and age, most obj-c coders are still manually reconciling their header and implementation files!

Comment: This app does not work in most cases, if I want a declaration of an method that has been fully implemented, then often it keeps getting it wrong. Here is an example with an short method implementation with an for loop in it, accessorizer makes this:

    -(void) shuffleTiles;
    ++i);
    - i; NSUInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i; [tiles       exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n]; } };

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any existing tools (although Interface Builder does allow you to define outlets and actions, and then generate a header and implementation skeleton for you based on those). Remember though that the implementation file can contain information that should not go in the header (such as private methods and instance variables/properties), so it would be difficult for any tool to do this in any case.

For the moment, in Xcode, you can [split the window](http://mobileorchard.com/14-essential-xcode-tips-tricks-and-resources-for-iphone-devs/) and see both side by side (in Xcode 4, this is the Assistant). Alternatively, you can press Alt-Command-UpArrow to see the corresponding file.